# Heroku deploy with vitejs error H10 (vite: not found)

Tags: node.js, heroku, vite

I'm trying to deploy my frontEnd app in heroku but only what I get is errors.I was fixing error by error, but i do not know what to do with that one.

by the way I'm using vitejs

the error what i get from heroku logs

```
2021-07-30T11:30:06.680426+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm run dev`
2021-07-30T11:30:10.593125+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-07-30T11:30:10.593146+00:00 app[web.1]: > myapp@1.0.0 dev
2021-07-30T11:30:10.593146+00:00 app[web.1]: > vite
2021-07-30T11:30:10.593146+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-07-30T11:30:10.614517+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: vite: not found
2021-07-30T11:30:10.686497+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2021-07-30T11:30:10.789749+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-07-30T11:38:04.881585+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=example.herokuapp.com dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

my package.json

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "description": "a really cool app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "engines": {
    "node": "<=16.x.x",
    "npm": "<=7.x.x"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "17.0.0",
    "react-dom": "17.0.0",
    "styled-components": "5.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vitejs/plugin-react-refresh": "1.3.1",
    "vite": "2.4.2"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react-spring": "^9.2.4"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Found the solution here :
https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/1215

You have to unset the production mode of npm env or yarn env, as :

```
heroku config:set NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false YARN_PRODUCTION=false
```

or if you use dokku :

```
dokku config:set my-app NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false YARN_PRODUCTION=false
```

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else that encounters this, I was able to fix the issue with deploying static vite/react apps on heroku using the serve package.  The 1 answer shown didn't work for me, though it helped with the error, Vite was then deploying it's own development server rather than serving from Heroku.

Install serve from npm

```
  npm i serve
```

Move “vite” from devDependencies into dependencies, which should now look like this:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.15.0",
    "serve": "^14.2.1",
    "vite": "^4.4.5"
  },
```

Update `start` and `heroku-postbuild` scripts in package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "vite": "vite",
    "server": "nodemon server.cjs",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm:server\" \"npm:vite\"",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "start": "serve -s dist",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm run build"
  },
```

Create a Procfile (no extension, capital ‘P’)

```
web: npm run start
```

Commit your changes and push to Heroku.